# Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit's Automatic Update is stuck

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update, dotnet-framework

I need to install .NET framework 3.5SP1 on Windows server 2008R2 64 bit server, but windows is not allowing me to do this manually. I tried to do this with Windows Update, but Windows update is stuck in downloading, at 0%. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that the Setup Process for .NET has changed in 2008 R2. There is also a MSDN [Blog Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlblog/how-to-installenable-net-3-5-sp1-on-windows-server-2008-r2-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2) outlining the current procedure.

So following there example let's make sure .NET is correctly installed. Therefore you can issue these Powershell commands:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "as-NET-Framework" } | format-list Displayname,Installed
```

Check that it says `Installed:True`. If the .NET Feature is not activated you can do so by issueing:

```
Add-WindowsFeature as-net-framework
```

If the feature is installed, and the problem with downloading persists you could try removing and reinstalling the .NET Framework from Scratch (uninstall the Feature, reboot, reinstall) and update with a clean installation.

Comment: the feature was installed, and finally formatting and reinstalling solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821). It tends to help in similar situations where updates are broken, stuck or failing all the time.